# Не отображается текстура после запекания

Tags: blender

Моя модель + текстура не отображаются.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Что я должен сделать, чтобы текстура отобразилась, запеклась?

Файлы: [здесь](https://www.dropbox.com/s/94x4b5cxbub6su2/WoodTable.blend?dl=0) + [здесь](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kltlrysomocp0m/WoodTable.blend1?dl=0).

Изображение для верха стола.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UV которое получилось после запекания.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно настроить материалы. Эта тема столь обширна, что я могу лишь предложить вам начать изучать это по учебникам или видеоурокам. Вот, например, что я нашел для вас:

https://younglinux.info/blender/material.php

https://blender3d.com.ua/texturirovanie-v-blender/

Answer (score 0):

А зачем Вы запекаете Ambient Occlusion (на скриншоте), если Вы хотите запечь канал текстуры?
Для AO вы запекаете отдельное изображение и затем это миксуется с каналом текстуры в материале. Можно это реализовать как обычным способом, так и через Ноды.

Примерно так:
Сначала запекаем Текстуру в изображение и **сохраняем** получившееся изображение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем запекаем АО в новую текстуру и также сохраняем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сохранение изображения осуществляется через редактор UV:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее строим НОДы (если в Blender Render, то примерно так может быть):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ставим режим Rendered и смотрим результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно подробней в вашем ответе об обычном способе и через Ноды. Если будут скриншоты, то это совсем замечательно.

Comment: Добавил пример в комментарий.